# How to instantiate a Java abstract class with a constructor parameter with a groovy closure

Tags: java, groovy, abstract-class

I am trying to instantiate a Java abstract class from my Groovy code. Considering the following Java abstract class (non relevant processing is stripped out from the class):

```
public abstract class StackOverflow{
  public abstract String answerMe();
}
```

I can easily instantiate it in Groovy this way, and the call to `answerMe()` will trigger the correct output:

```
StackOverflow stack = [answerMe : { "Answer" }] as StackOverflow
```

Now if I modify the `StackOverflow` class adding a String parameter in the constructor like this :

```
public abstract class StackOverflowStr{
  public StackOverflowStr(String s){}
  public abstract String answerMe();
}
```

I don't really know how to instantiate my object, I tried a lot of thing, but I can't seem to find the right syntax, does someone got any clue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instantiate it in classic Java style:

```
StackOverflowStr stack = new StackOverflowStr("javaish"){
    String answerMe() {"answer"}
}
```

Comment: Thanks I did it this way but I was wondering if I can with a closure as in the first example.

Comment: @CedricGatay No, if there's no default constructor, you can't create a proxy object without doing what Andrea says

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, and to be clear on wording: in all of these scenarios, you're not instantiating an abstract class.

Abstract classes are classes that can never be instantiated.

You're instantiating a concrete anonymous class that extends an abstract class.  B-)